# How to create one master condition for activerecord usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have many tables that have the user_id field and I want to filter all the queries to these tables by appending a where clause for this user_id. How would I be able to achieve it in Rails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're thinking of this backwards. Search those tables through the user object that you have, ensuring that they are already associated in ActiveRecord. So, if you have a table called magazines, you'd use something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :magazines

#app/models/magazine.rb
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

Then you can reference all of a user's magazines through an instance of a user:

```
@user = User.first
@user.magazines.all
```

That will return all magazines that have a user_id equal to the user's ID.

Comment: Hmm, that's true, didn't think of it this way. Thanks!